# SuiteCRM authentication with third party OAUTH2 server

Tags: suitecrm

I want to integrate OAUTH2 server with SuiteCRM, Please anyone have idea about process or steps OAUTH2 integration.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the section called "Connectors" in the official Sugar CRM 6.5 guide (suiteCRM is based on it), it's very detailed.

You can then integrate the results of whatever you get back from the API into a dashlet. Here's the guide http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Unsupported_Versions/Sugar_6.5/index.html

Comment: Hello Robert, Thanks for your replay.

Comment: np, there's also a bunch of examples of how you can ping an API and get back a response that you can then manipulate. There's built-in suiteCRM functions that take care of cURL requests. You can put them in a custom entry point as a test